# run-program in another directory

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, external-process, ccl

SBCL's `sb-ext:run-program` has an argument called `directory`. When you pass it, the program you specify will be run in that directory, rather than your `cwd`.

Is there any way of getting the same effect using `ccl:run-program`?